# Matlab - How to make a figure current? How to make an axes current?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

If `f` is the figure handle, I wanted to use `plot3(..)` on it just like I would use `plot(..)`, but this didn't work:

```
>> plot3(f, t, real(Y), imag(Y))
Error using plot3
Vectors must be the same lengths.
```

Then I figured out that the way to do this is to:

1. First make the relevant figure *current*.
2. Then use the `plot3(..)` function.

I can find what the current figure is using `gcf`, but how do I make a figure current (via its handle)?

Comment: By the way, if we don't have a reference to an axes object, then we can (1) `aa = findobj(gcf, 'type', 'axes')`, then (2) `cellfun(@(x) disp(x), get(aa, 'position'))`, from which we can tell which subplot is which, then (3) `axes(aa(2))` for example, to make the second axes object _current_.

Comment: (While for figures, the _current_ status seems to change with focus.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This method has my personal preference:

```
set(0, 'currentfigure', f);  %# for figures
set(f, 'currentaxes', axs);  %# for axes with handle axs on figure f
```

because these commands are their own documentation. I find

```
figure(f)
```

and the like confusing on first read -- do you create a new figure? or merely make an existing one active? -> more reading of the context is required.

Comment: Another advantage is that Matlab does not explicitly set the visibility to 'on' with this but retains the former visibility of the figure.

Comment: I take your point WRT readability, but is the 1st line really more readable? WTF is 0? Man I hate Matlab.

Comment: @ensignr Every programming language has its quirks, no need to start bashing. What's good is that `0` has been replaced in more recent MATLAB with `groot` -- the graphics root object. Makes more sense.

Answer (score 9):

It is actually as simple as feeding the `f` back into the `figure(..)` command:

```
figure(f)    %Makes the figure current.
```

Also, if I did something like this:

```
f = figure('IntegerHandle','off');    % With unique, non-reusable handle.
top = subplot(2, 1, 1);
bot = subplot(2, 1, 2);
```

Then I can make the *axes* `top` or `bottom` current by issuing a command like this:

```
subplot(top);
```

This also works:

```
axes(top);
```

But the two types of handles cannot be intermixed: `axes(..)` and `subplot(..)` work on axes handles, while `figure(..)` works on figure handles.

Comment: Damn, Matlab sucks sometimes. Seriously, Mathworks, why can't you add the `axes_handle` parameter to `plot3` ?

Answer (score 4):

While others have provided you exactly what you've asked for (how to make an axes or figure the current one). My preferred way for dealing with this, is to explicitly specify the parent of your plot in the call to `plot3`.

If you look at the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html), you will see that you can specify the parent axes as the first parameter to the function. If looks like you attempted to do this in your example, but you provided a handle to a **figure** rather than an **axes**.

```
f = figure()
ax = axes('Parent', f)
im = plot3(ax, X, Y, Z);
```

Alternately, I prefer the explicit solution

```
im = plot3(X, Y, Z, 'Parent', ax)
```

The nice thing about this explicit parameter/value specification of the parent is that it is accepted by **all** graphics objects. Functions like `plot` and `plot3` are actually helper functions that wrap the functionality of `line` and allow for the convention of passing the parent first. The parameter/value approach is widely accepted regardless of whether you're working with a higher level function (`plot`, `plot3`, `imshow`) or the lower level objects (`line`, `image`, etc.)

The two benefits here are that you remove the overhead of MATLAB trying to figure out where to put your plot and also, it prevents MATLAB from having to change which figure is currently displayed, forcing a re-rendering which is one of MATLAB's slowest tasks.

Answer (score 0):

give handle name to figure, give you a little example

```
  f1 = figure;
  imshow(image1);
  f2 = figure;
  imshow(image2);
  % edit image 1
  figure(f1);
  text(2,3,'done');
```